# What's the Sequel equivalent of ActiveRecord's `select_value`?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sequel

[ActiveRecord's `select_value`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_value) is a very convenient way to grab the first col of the first row (e.g., `"1"`)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('SELECT 1')
```

How do I do that in [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/)? The closest I've gotten is

```
DB['SELECT 1'].first.values.first # ugly
```

Answer (score 3):

`DB['SELECT 1'].get` or `DB.get(1)`